# Problems while moving data of Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, user-profiles, migration, data-migration

I would like to move my Thunderbird settings and data to a new computer. I am using the method described [HERE](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer), and I remember I managed to do it before like this. It seems like everything is copied perfectly when I **first** open Thunderbird, however when I close it and open it again, it shows empty windows and this "error message" in the bottom:

```
           <key id="save-key"
 ----------^


       <label value="&event.statusbarpanel.privacy.label;"/>
 ------^


             <toolbarbutton id="todaypane-new-event-button"
 ------------^
```

I even tried to specify the profile folder using `thunderbird -profilemanager`, and also installing all extensions first so that the environment is identical, but no luck.

I noticed that after the first (and last) successful launch, the following files are being modified my Thunderbird:

```
panacea.dat
prefs.js
extensions.json
session.json
xulstore.json
addonStartup.json.lz4
\ImapMail\[email1]\user.sbd\auk.msf
\Mail\smart mailboxes\Drafts.msf
\Mail\smart mailboxes\Inbox.msf
\Mail\smart mailboxes\Junk.msf
\webaccountMail\[email2].msf
```

but that tells me little information on what is happening. Any advice?

Comment: Same OS? Moving Thunderbird profile worked, for me, between Windows & Windows, or Linux & Linux, but EOL character differences made it unfeasible with mixed OS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik same OS yes, both Win10

Comment: Have you tried copying the entire Profile, and then pointing Thunderbird to that profile? That also brings over extra data, such as emails, but it can easily be cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had this problem. My solution was to remove the Lightning extension an re-install it. It was a bit complicated, because a lot of menus were not available. This is how I did it:

- restart tb with the Profile Manager, (using windowskey-r, browse to Thunderbird.exe, and then add a space and -P)
- make a new profile,
  but use the Choose directory button to select the existing, transferred profile.
- tick the "use this profile by default.
- Start tb... Doesn't work! Close it again.
- Hold the Shift key down while starting tb again to enter the thunderbird safe mode.
- Disable all addons and extensions.
- Use the Tools/Addons menu to remove any extensions which might be causing the problem.
  When it starts correctly in normal mode, without holding the Shift key, try adding your extensions.

Comment: Does it still work if you close and open the program multiple times? I'll try this method the next time I'm migrating, thank you!